# python / dpkt: Find out if packet is a tcp packet or a udp packet ,

Tags: python, network-programming, pcap, libpcap, packet-capture

I have a python scripts that captures the packets on the ethernet using dpkt, but how do i differentiate between which packets are tcp and which ones are for udp.

Eventually i would like to have a list of packets for each tcp connection that was established during the time interval.

my code is:

```
import dpkt
import pcapy
cap=pcap.open_live('eth0',100000,1,0)
(header,payload)=cap.next()
while header:
    eth=dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(str(payload))
    ip=eth.data
    tcp=ip.data 
    # i need to know whether it is a tcp or  a udp packet here!!!
    (header,payload)=cap.next()
```

Comment: I found the answer so i might as well post it here for others.

The following code does the job:

    ip=eth.data
    if (ip.__dict).has_key('tcp'):
        #then this is a tcp packet...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IP header contains field protocol. dpkt should allow you to obtain this value and using it you can guess what is on top of IP. Here is a list of valid protocols numbers http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xml.
UDP is equal to 17 while TCP is 6.

Edit:
I have checked this issue and as I mentioned dpkg provide `p` properties to access protocol field of IP. So you can check agains it. But it also automatically parse packet and set `data` property to instance of class that represent upper protocol like UDP or TCP. So you can check type of `data` property and you recognize this protocol.

```
from dpkt.ip import IP, IP_PROTO_UDP
from dpkt.udp import UDP
ip = IP('E\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x11r\xc0\x01\x02\x03\x04\x01\x02\x03\x04\x00o\x00\xde\x00\x0e\xbf5foobar')
#if ip.p == IP_PROTO_UDP:  # checking for protocol field in ip header
if type(ip.data) == UDP :  # checking of type of data that was recognized by dpkg
    udp = ip.data
    print udp.sport
else:
    print "Not UDP"
```

Answer (score 10):

A python script that captures the packets on the ethernet adapter `eth0` using [dpkt](https://github.com/kbandla/dpkt), and differentiates between **TCP** and **UDP** packets of the **IP**.

```
import dpkt
import pcapy

cap=pcapy.open_live('eth0',100000,1,0)
(header,payload)=cap.next()

while header:
    eth=dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(str(payload))

    # Check whether IP packets: to consider only IP packets 
    if eth.type!=dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP:
            continue
            # Skip if it is not an IP packet
    ip=eth.data
    if ip.p==dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_TCP: # Check for TCP packets
           TCP=ip.data 
           # ADD TCP packets Analysis code here
    elif ip.p==dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_UDP: # Check for UDP packets
           UDP=ip.data 
           # UDP packets Analysis code here

    (header,payload)=cap.next()
```